# How to define parameters(page, filter fields, etc) automatically to custom list_route URL similar to list() in ModelViewSet?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am having trouble figuring out how to automatically add page and filter fields to list_route URL
I already have the regular "list" action, from modelviewset working, and it automatically supports the page, and filter_fields defined as parameters to the list URL

What I would like to do is to define a list_detail URL through the list_route(), with "automatic" support for page and filter fields similar the list() action. 
So I modeled the code in list_detail() method to be exactly the same as the list() method in ListViewSet mixin.
My goal is to add a DetailedSerializer to list_detail so it lists more details than list() action and support both actions.
I am not able to get the URL to support page, volume and srcvolume parameters from the automatic pagination and filter backends.

Any ideas how to do this?

```
class MirrorVolumeViewSet(views.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = MirrorVolume.objects.all()
    serializer_class = volserializers.MirrorVolumeSerializer
    filter_fields = ('volume', 'srcvolume')

    @list_route()
    def list_detail(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Get list with details '''
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Think this has more to do with schema generation.
pagination and other params are not being added into the schemas.py:is_list_view() not treating the list_route() views as list views.

probably a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the current schema generator code in the rest framework does not recognize the new action/method list_detail as a "list" operation. It is hard coded to look 'list' as the name.

My solution was to override the schema generator with something like the following. This essentially duplicates the current Schema generator code as is an overrides the code that recognizes the list method to be more flexlible

urls.py

```
from wit.swaggerschema import get_swagger_view
router = DefaultRouter()
schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='WIT API')
```

swaggerschema.py
    from rest_framework import exceptions
    from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
    from rest_framework.renderers import CoreJSONRenderer
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from rest_framework.schemas import SchemaGenerator
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
    from rest_framework.compat import coreapi, urlparse

```
from rest_framework_swagger.views import renderers


class WITSchemaGenerator(SchemaGenerator):
    ''' Custom Schema generator to support parameters for list and detail route '''

    def is_list_view(self, path, method, view):  # pylint: disable=locally-disabled, no-self-use
        """
        Return True if the given path/method appears to represent a list view.
        """
        if hasattr(view, 'action'):
            # Viewsets have an explicitly defined action, which we can inspect.
            return view.action.startswith('list')

        if method.lower() != 'get':
            return False
        path_components = path.strip('/').split('/')
        if path_components and '{' in path_components[-1]:
            return False
        return True

    def get_pagination_fields(self, path, method, view):
        if not self.is_list_view(path, method, view):
            return []

        if not getattr(view, 'pagination_class', None):
            return []

        paginator = view.pagination_class()
        return paginator.get_schema_fields(view)

    def get_filter_fields(self, path, method, view):
        if not self.is_list_view(path, method, view):
            return []

        if not getattr(view, 'filter_backends', None):
            return []

        fields = []
        for filter_backend in view.filter_backends:
            fields += filter_backend().get_schema_fields(view)
        return fields

    def get_custom_fields(self, path, method, view):  # pylint: disable=locally-disabled, no-self-use, unused-argument
        ''' Add custom parameters to schema fields '''
        if not getattr(view, 'get_schema_fields', None):
            return []

        return view.get_schema_fields(view)

    def get_link(self, path, method, view):
        """
        Return a `coreapi.Link` instance for the given endpoint.
        """
        fields = self.get_path_fields(path, method, view)
        fields += self.get_serializer_fields(path, method, view)
        fields += self.get_pagination_fields(path, method, view)
        fields += self.get_filter_fields(path, method, view)
        fields += self.get_custom_fields(path, method, view)

        if fields and any([field.location in ('form', 'body') for field in fields]):
            encoding = self.get_encoding(path, method, view)
        else:
            encoding = None

        description = self.get_description(path, method, view)

        if self.url and path.startswith('/'):
            path = path[1:]

        return coreapi.Link(
            url=urlparse.urljoin(self.url, path),
            action=method.lower(),
            encoding=encoding,
            fields=fields,
            description=description
        )


def get_swagger_view(title=None, url=None, patterns=None, urlconf=None):
    """
    Returns schema view which renders Swagger/OpenAPI.
    """

    class WITSwaggerSchemaView(APIView):
        ''' Custom WIT Swagger Schema View '''
        _ignore_model_permissions = True
        exclude_from_schema = True
        permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        renderer_classes = [
            CoreJSONRenderer,
            renderers.OpenAPIRenderer,
            renderers.SwaggerUIRenderer
        ]

        def get(self, request):  # pylint: disable=locally-disabled, no-self-use
            ''' get a shema to return '''
            generator = WITSchemaGenerator(
                title=title,
                url=url,
                patterns=patterns,
                urlconf=urlconf
            )
            schema = generator.get_schema(request=request)

            if not schema:
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(
                    'The schema generator did not return a schema Document'
                )

            return Response(schema)

    return WITSwaggerSchemaView.as_view()
```